# - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I inserted an NSLog and a UIAlertView into this function call. When I pressed the home button, the NSLog executed, but not the UIAlertView. Why is that?

Comment: Because you cannot open UIAlertViews when the app is in the background? :)

Comment: So where can I insert a UIAlertView that pops up just before the program exits or goes to the background?

Comment: I think about this.  I am using your application and the phone rings?  I want to answer the call, which means I will exit your application.  Why would you want to display an alert box to me? The better question is what are you trying to achieve by showing the alert box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it in `applicationWillResignActive` (not tested).  It gets called before `applicationDidEnterBackground`.  But I think you should rethink throwing up an alert box for the 5 secs before iOS kills it.